# PyQt5 How to Instantiate Multiple Ui in Main Ui

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, instance, pyqt5

I need to instantiate 2 Ui in my MainWindow. This code works if I only instantiate 1 Ui:

```
    self.loginWindow = QtWidgets.QDialog(MainWindow)
    self.ui = Ui_LogInWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self.loginWindow)
    self.loginWindow.setModal(True)
    self.loginWindow.show()
```

However, when I try to do it for my other Ui, it creates errors:

```
    self.loginWindow = QtWidgets.QDialog(MainWindow)
    self.ui = Ui_LogInWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self.loginWindow)
    self.loginWindow.setModal(True)
    self.loginWindow.show()


    self.profileWindow = QtWidgets.QDialog(MainWindow)
    self.ui = Ui_ProfileWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self.profileWindow)
    self.profileWindow.setModal(True)
    #self.profileWindow.show()
```

The thing is, I need the widgets on both **Ui_LogInWindow** and **Ui_ProfileWindow** in my **MainWindow**. I do not how to make it work if I cannot instantiate the two properly. I'm new to PyQt and Python, that's why I do not know much of the syntax. Help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want. Could you provide a minimal working example? Or a picture, maybe?

Comment: what i meant was, how do i instantiate two or more Ui inside my main ui. i do not understand the concept of parent and child relationship in instantiating, that's why the second part of the shown codes above won't work; and the first shown code works.

Comment: So you want 2 different UIs to be shown simultaneously on one window? How you expect it to look: be side-by-side, overlay one another? Or you want two separate windows which can be shows independently?

Comment: two seperate windows that can show independently. you see, i have widgets inside each window that i will later use, and is connected to the widgets inside my main window. that's why, i need to learn how to instantiate two or more Ui inside my main Ui

Comment: Your attempt to have more than one modal window at the same time breaks the very idea of window modality. What you probably want is modeless window. More about modality in Qt is here http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#details

Comment: ohh thanks. i'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you setup both UI in one instance of the class. Rather then doing that, you better create two separate classes for each window.

A small example of two-window app.

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 100)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Wow such button', self)
        self.button.move(40, 20)


class App2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(400, 100, 200, 200)
        self.editor = QtWidgets.QTextEdit('Wow such text', self)
        self.editor.setGeometry(20, 20, 160, 160)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = App()
    gui2 = App2()
    gui.show()
    gui2.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Note that it isn't necessary to create all windows at once. I slightly modified example above so now only first window is shown on startup. You can use button to toggle second window's visibility.

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 100)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Toggle second window', self)
        self.button.setGeometry(20, 20, 160, 30)

        self.app2 = App2()
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.toggle_app2)

    def toggle_app2(self):
        if self.app2.isHidden():
            self.app2.show()
        else:
            self.app2.hide()


class App2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(400, 100, 200, 200)
        self.editor = QtWidgets.QTextEdit('Wow such text', self)
        self.editor.setGeometry(20, 20, 160, 160)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = App()
    gui.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Hope that will point you in the right direction

Comment: thanks for the response. but, i have 3 **.py** files that contains my **Ui**s. 1 for my main window(that will call the two ui file), and 1 for each of the other two. how do i implement what you have just told me?

based from what i have understood on your response, the other two ui are made inside the main window; which is not my case.

thanks a lot. kudos to you

Comment: how do i implement what you have just said when i need to import my other 2 ui, so i can use the widgets inside of em? furthermore, my 2 ui are both found on 2 different .py file. i hope this clears my concerns. thank you very much

Comment: Well, just import both UIs in the mainwindow file and create instance's of them in mainwindow's `__init__`. After that you would be able to access their widgets.

Comment: i'm having an error when i instantiate both UIs. but when i instantiate only 1 UI, it doesn't create any error. i'm having this error when i instantiate both UI: `AttributeError: 'Ui_ProfileWindow' object has no attribute 'LogIn'` i have have instantiated my two ui like the one in my question (having the lines with `.setModal(True)` removed). `LogIn` is a button in my other UI.

Comment: That is because you overwrite `self.ui`s value. Try something like this: 
`self.loginWindow = QtWidgets.QDialog(MainWindow)`
`self.loginWindow.ui = Ui_LogInWindow()`
`self.loginWindow.ui.setupUi(self.loginWindow)`
Adapt it for ProfileWindow accordingly

Comment: i have tried your answer. but it now resulted to another error: `AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'ui'` for my line of code: `self.ui.LogIn.clicked.connect(self.LogInClick)`

Comment: Because now your widgets are stores in each dialor's `ui` attribute. You should reference to them as `self.loginWindow.ui` or `self.profileWindow.ui` depending on which dialog contains widget.

Comment: WOW, THAT'S AMAZING. that cleared up a lot of confusion. i think i understand now. thanks, @mFoxRU !!!